# Find the run length of 1 in column number 1,3,5 and find count of continuous two 1 in column 2,4,6 data is in data frame of R

Tags: r

I have data as a data frame in R:

```
> qa
   A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
1    1   1   1   1   1   1
2    1   1   1   1   1   1
3    1   0   1   0   1   1
4    1   1   1   0   1   1
5    1   1   1   1   1   0
6    0   0   1   1   1   1
7    0   0   1   1   1   1
8    0   1   1   0   0   0
9    1   1   1   0   0   0
10   1   1   1   1   0   1
```

Kindly suggest the best way to achieve the following result.

```
> qc
  A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
1   5   2  10   2   7   2
```

In the above data frame:
A_1 = 5  (Maximum number of runs in `qa$A_1`), 
A_2 = 2  (there are two continuous 1 in reference to A_1=5),
B_1 = 10 (Maximum number of runs in `qa$B_1`),
B_2 = 2  (there are two continuous 1 in reference to of B_1=10),
C_1 = 7  (Maximum number of runs in `qa$C_1`),
C_2 = 2  (there are three continuous 1 in reference to of C_1=7)

Comment: Are you wanting the sum of the continuous successful runs?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on in the ?_2 columns, it seems you want something beside the length of the first stretch of 1's.

Comment: @C T Hall your answer is correct, i wrongly defined column C_2 in the qa data frame.

Comment: if the column  C_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0) , than the result corresponding it is 5, but the required result is 2 because there are only 2 pairs of one in C_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
qa <- data.frame(A_1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1),
                 A_2 = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1),
                 B_1 = rep(1,10),
                 B_2 = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1),
                 C_1 = c(rep(1,7),0,0,0),
                 C_2 = c(1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1))
```

`rle` gives you run length encoding, so we can use that to extract the first continuous stretch of runs.

Base R

```
sapply(qa, function(x) with (rle(x), lengths[values == 1][1]))
```

output:

```
A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2 
  5   2  10   2   7   4
```

or if you prefer the `tidyverse` package:

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(qa, ~rle(.)$lengths[rle(.)$values==1][1])
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
    A_1   A_2   B_1   B_2   C_1   C_2
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     5     2    10     2     7     4
```

or if you want a data.frame instead of a tibble you can convert it:

```
>as.data.frame(map_dfr(qa, ~rle(.)$lengths[rle(.)$values==1][1]))
    A_1 A_2 B_1 B_2 C_1 C_2
1   5   2  10   2   7   4
```

Comment: Thanks to CT Hall and d.b for your response. But the required result for C_2 is not matching, kindly suggest in it.

Comment: In odd numbered column i am trying to find continuous pair of 1's i,e C_2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), first pair with first two observation in vector C_2, second pair in the vector i,e third and fourth observation. fifth observation should not consider because it is not a pair.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to think about this and get back to you.

Comment: By this logic, shouldn't A_2 = 3?

Comment: A_2 is not 3 because we should consider the data based on run length column i,e 1,3,5. where their is maximum run length(1,3,5) corresponding data should consider from column (2,4,6).